# Braintree drop-in payment form submission to be intercepted by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, braintree

In the simple javascript drop-in UI, when the [form](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/start/hello-client) is being submitted, braintree.js will intercept the form submission and inserts a hidden field named "payment_method_nonce" into the form, before the submission actually goes to the server.

However, when using the AngularJS as the frontend framework, I generally don't want the form submission to directly go to the server and then do a page reload. Instead, I want my AngularJS function to intercept and deal with the form submission (e.g., via ng-click or ng-submit), AND in its processing it needs to retrieve and use the "payment_method_nonce" value.

I tried it and it can still intercept the form submission. However, it seems like AngularJS intercepts the form submission BEFORE braintree.js does and inserts the "payment_method_nonce" field.

Hence, my AngularJS code that responds to the form submission cannot retrieve that "payment_method_nonce" field and perform appropriate processing. Any suggestions on how I can work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: After reading more braintree docs, it turns out registering a paymentMethodNonceReceived callback when setting up the braintree gateway is the right way to go!

Comment: I work at Braintree. Glad you figured it out! You should post that as an answer -- it's totally fine to answer your own question.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code for this because I have specified the paymentMethodNonceReceived and cannot get the call back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading more braintree docs, it turns out registering a paymentMethodNonceReceived callback when setting up the braintree gateway is the right way to go!

Comment: Note that this function has been replaced with  `onPaymentMethodReceived`, however the way of using it and the resulting behaviour remain the same. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/javascript/v2

Comment: Could you post your sample code and show how you did it? Having same problem using angular